# How to skip fail test cases in mobile application testing by appium and selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am getting a problem in the testing of multiple test case of different module in mobile application. I want to run 10 test cases and in each test case having many steps written in each page. I wrote my test case by the help of TestNg. So my problem is that when I run my test case and if any one test case get failed then due to this the other test cases also get failed. I am using Selenium webdriver, java  for Automating my test cases.

So my question is what I have to do if I want to skip the failed test case and switch to the next module(it means on pages).Even I don't have home button in the all page.
Please guyz help me

Comment: I am not familiar with TestNg but it sounds to me like you have dependencies between your test cases. If that is the case you should write your test cases so that each can be run independently that way one failure does not cause a cascade of failures.

Comment: Seems like you are running tests in a row. Meaning you start the app and try to run all the tests with that instance. If you want them to work this, then you need to handle it on the code. I usually start and close the app after each test, but it all depends on your needs.

Comment: @MadisKangro  thanks for reply me